# ggplot2 : Bland Altman and Smoothline from different variables on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am trying to make a Bland Altman graph from 4 different variables, making it 2 different sets of points on the same graph using ggplot2

```
> head(BAall)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
formule    sd  avg.dif    pre.dif   pre.moy  post.dif post.moy order
<fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     CGa 16.31 13.03265  38.314256 116.35713 13.730425 32.26521     4
2     CGa 16.31 13.03265  10.821745  46.21087 17.414900 55.10745     4
3     CGa 16.31 13.03265 -15.038191  60.08090 -7.110499 56.34475     4
4     CGa 16.31 13.03265 -14.797744  86.10113 -5.071287 73.26436     4
5     CGa 16.31 13.03265   5.499377 112.64969 12.236626 73.41831     4
6     CGa 16.31 13.03265  19.835531  80.11777 12.712211 80.25611     4
> ggplot (BAall) +
  +   geom_point (aes(pre.moy , pre.dif), color = "red") +
  +   geom_point (aes(post.moy , post.dif), color = "blue") +
  +   geom_hline (yintercept = mean(BAall$avg.dif) + c(-2,0,2) * mean(BAall$sd))
```

This works pretty well, giving this :
[My Bland Altman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wvd0.png)

The problem appears when I want to add a smoothline using
 - `pre.moy AND post.moy` on the x-axis

- `pre.dif AND post.dif` on the y-axis

I tried to concatenate these variables but I get this

```
> ggplot (BAall) +
  +   geom_point (aes(pre.moy , pre.dif), color = "red") +
  +   geom_point (aes(post.moy , post.dif), color = "blue") +
  +   geom_hline (yintercept = mean(BAall$avg.dif) + c(-2,0,2) * mean(BAall$sd)) +
  +   geom_smooth (aes(c(BAall$pre.moy,BAall$post.moy),c(BAall$pre.moy,BAall$post.dif)))
Error : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (162): x, y
```

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to smooth? You can't supply concatenated values to geom_smooth - this just puts the two columns end on end, doubling the number of points for no reason that I can see, and leading to the error message you got.   I can't see what you are trying to achieve here. Could you please explain?

Comment: I want to smooth a line taking pre.moy and post.moy values as x values and pre.dif and post. dif values. The thing is pre.moy and post.moy are same measurements taken at different times (same for pre.dif and post.dif) , so I wanted 2 different geom_point with 2 different colors. But it causes trouble when i want to use geom_smooth for everything at the same time